# Ошибка This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized

Tags: python, pyqt5

> This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Выскочила такая проблема, когда я решила проверить код.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = QWidget()
    w.resize(250, 150)
    w.move(300, 300)
    w.setWindowTitle('Simple')
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Что делать я не знаю. Пыталась разобраться в этом *https://habr.com/post/188816/* , но ничего не поняла. Можете объяснить, как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Как pyqt5 ставили?

Comment: В File/Settings установила пакет PyQt5 в PyCharm

Comment: А какая версия питона? 3.6, 3.7? Какой результат от команды в консоли `pip install -U pyqt5`?

Comment: Версия 3.7.0 А в консоли такое выдало "Collecting pyqt5
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a7/2d/d2c989006c86ae98ed230c28c3e0dd7fa0374e723afc107d12268159ceb7/PyQt5-5.11.3-5.11.2-cp35.cp36.cp37.cp38-none-win_amd64.whl"

Comment: И после pip'а проблема повторяется?

Comment: Немного не поняла, что означает "после pip'a"?

Comment: Я не дописала. В консоле такое выдало: Collecting pyqt5
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a7/2d/d2c989006c86ae98ed230c28c3e0dd7fa0374e723afc107d12268159ceb7/PyQt5-5.11.3-5.11.2-cp35.cp36.cp37.cp38-none-win_amd64.whl
Collecting PyQt5_sip<4.20,>=4.19.11 (from pyqt5)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/46/86/0e35563d0c67c3f6b50e344624b87bfa7e720e1c99e64115a937ab7f6718/PyQt5_sip-4.19.13-cp37-none-win_amd64.whl
Installing collected packages: PyQt5-sip, pyqt5
Successfully installed PyQt5-sip-4.19.13 pyqt5-5.11.3

Comment: После того как вы выполнили команду `pip` снова запускали код? Ошибка повторилась?

Comment: Может мне эти два файла, которые скачались необходимо куда-то добавить?

Comment: Да, ошибка никуда не ушла.

Comment: [Скачал python3.7.0 64 битный](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.0/python-3.7.0-amd64.exe), установил. В консоли прописал `pip install pyqt5`. Началась установка `Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a7/2d/d2c989006c86ae98ed230c28c3e0dd7fa0374e723afc107d12268159ceb7/PyQt5-5.11.3-5.11.2-cp35.cp36.cp37.cp38-none-win_amd64.whl (93.4MB)`. После попробовал ваш код -- работает. Не знаю... Попробуйте переустановить питон